# How to automatically classify the Outlook email sensitivity for Azure Information Protection in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, azure, outlook

I'm developing a windows from using vb.net, trying to send an email through outlook. My code is running fine, but once it reaches the send() line, a pop-up of Azure Information Protection to select the email sensitivity (Public, Confidential, ...etc), so the email will not be sent until a user select.

I tried ( **OutlookMessage.Sensitivity = outlook.OlSensitivity.olNormal** )
but still, need some one to select the classification from the Azure pop-up, full code shown below...

```
Dim OutlookMessage As outlook.MailItem 
Dim AppOutlook As New outlook.Application 
Try
 OutlookMessage = AppOutlook.CreateItem(outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
 Dim Recipents As outlook.Recipients = OutlookMessage.Recipients Recipents.Add("myemail@hotmail.com") 
 OutlookMessage.Subject = "Sending through Outlook" 
 OutlookMessage.Body = "Testing outlook Mail" 
 OutlookMessage.BodyFormat = outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML
 OutlookMessage.Sensitivity = outlook.OlSensitivity.olNormal 
 OutlookMessage.Send() 
Catch ex As Exception 
 MessageBox.Show("Mail could not be sent") 'if you dont want this message, simply delete this line 
Finally 
 OutlookMessage = Nothing 
 AppOutlook = Nothing 
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoping that the code runs using a service account, do the below

1. Add the above service account inside the scoped AIP policy
2. Set a default label in the scoped policy

Doing this will not trigger the popup as a default label is already applied (I hope).

> Note: You can set different default labels for Outlook and other MS apps using AIp Policy's [advanced settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/information-protection/rms-client/client-admin-guide-customizations)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the best way to classify emails without getting
the popup through VBA code. The user needs to follow the following steps:

1. Create email template with sensitivity levels
   (Private,Public,Confidential,Normal).

   Open Outlook => CTRL + N  => Classify sensitivity =>File => Save AS template (Private.oft)=> Save.
2. Once the template is ready you can use the following code to send email without pop up

   ```
   Sub SendEmailWithoutPopupClassification()
   Dim origEmail As Outlook.MailItem 'To refer new outlook email
   Dim replyEmail As Outlook.MailItem 'To refer new outlook email
   Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application 'To refer to outlook application
   Dim Source As String

   Set replyEmail = Outlook.Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\akash\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Test Email.oft") replyEmail.To = "akashgupta.softs@gmail.com"
   replyEmail.Subject = "Test Email From Excel VBA" 
   replyEmail.HTMLBody = "Hi," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "This is my first email from Excel"

   Source = "C:\Users\guptakag\SampleAttachmentIfany.xlsb"

   replyEmail.Attachments.Add Source
   replyEmail.Send

   End Sub
   ```
3. Call the above function from Excel using a button.

Comment: I tried to fix the formatting but this was pretty messy; please review.